# Testing es5 with es6 testing framework (AVA)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, ava

I have an existing project written ecmascript5.
The project has no tests and I would like to add.
I used jasmine & mocha lightly (not lately...) and now I read about AVA (es6 out of the box)+Sinon and I really like it and I would like to try it.

There are several things I have problem figuring out (perhaps not possible) and I'll appreciate your insights.

I have a file 1.js and I would like to create tests for it at 1.test.js
How can I import\use objects\methods from there? I need to refactor the file to export es6 modules or there is an alternative solution? Furthermore, what happens if this file depends on jquery for example?

As I see it now, I need to convert my project to a full es6 project with babel+bundler(webpack) and then I'm good to go.

Another idea, is there a way for Ava to load a page, which loads all the scripts using script tags and thus everything will be available?

Do you have other suggestions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I upvoted this to help get it out of the hole.  I'm not sure why it got downvoted, seems to me a fair and honest question.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using es6 style. I exported assests from es5 files.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for posting the answer.  The question wasn't the one I was looking for, but I was glad to find it anyway.

Comment: manually. I migrated prototypes to class... you have es5 to es6 converters but I preffer doing this transformation manually.